# Why is OpenCV VideoCapture reading frames 4 times faster than FPS for my HLS stream

Tags: opencv, python

I am using the following code to read each frame from an HLS stream (I invoke init_camera, in the following, with an HLS URL).

I simply call read_camera_frame in a while loop (as fast as I can, since I believe the [VideoCapture](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#details) read should block and return frames at a rate that corresponds to the FPS of the video stream).

```
def init_camera(camera_id):
    return cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id)
```

```
        self.camera_cap = init_camera(self.image_info.get_camera_id())
```

```
    def read_camera_frame(self):
        syst = time.time_ns()

        time_since_last_pub = (syst - self.last_pub_time)/1000000000
        time_since_last_stat = (syst - self.last_stat_time)/1000000000

        if time_since_last_stat > self.stat_report_interval:
            fps = self.frames_collected_since_last_report/self.stat_report_interval
            self.logger.info(f"Total Frames: {self.frame_cnt}"
                             f"Total Discards: {self.frame_discard_cnt}"
                             f" Frames Since Last Report: {self.frames_collected_since_last_report} "
                             f" FPS:  {fps} "
                             )

            self.frames_collected_since_last_report = 0
            self.last_stat_time = syst

        self.logger.info(f"CameraReader: read a frame {self.frame_cnt}")
        ret, img = self.camera_cap.read()

        if ret:
            self.frame_cnt += 1
            self.frames_collected_since_last_report += 1
            ts = self.min_frame_pub_interval - time_since_last_pub
            if ts > 0:
                self.frame_discard_cnt += 1
                return []
            self.last_pub_time = syst
            return [(img, [copy.deepcopy(self.image_info)])]
        raise CameraReaderException("Failed To Read Frame")
```

The FPS for the video I am playing is just about 30.
[image]

```
        fps = self.camera_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        self.logger.info(f"Source FPS {fps}")
```

yet I see frames read at around 130 per second.
[image]

Why is the VideoCapture read returning frames roughly 4 times faster than I expect?

I thought the VideoCapture read would read frames at the FPS for the video.

Comment: OpenCV reads the frames as fast as possible. Example: when reading video frames from a local video file, the reading rate does not depend on the FPS of the video file (reading at 100fps from 1fps video file is normal). When grabbing video frames from a camera, the reading rate cannot exceed the FPS of the camera, because next frame is not available. The source of the HLS stream is probably a remote file (or buffered video), and not a live camera feed.

Comment: @rotem Yes I have set up the HLS service as well. So the source is absolutely as you describe. I didnt realize that read does not block. Based on your point, it sounds like i have to modulate the frame rate based on the desired FPS. I thought VideoCapture would do this. Ty for your feedback